# Conditional replace value in pandas dataframe with calculated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling with the following. I have a dataframe which has concentration values, which can be below detection limit (in this example <100 or <200)

```
df2 = DataFrame({"site":['site1','site2','site3','site4'],
                 "concentration":[12000,2000,'<100','<200']})
```

In order to plot the values, I'd like to replace the values <100 with 0.5 x the detection limit. So <100 becomes 50; <200 becomes . 
The code should then add a column TPH< to indicate which sites are below the detection limit.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mask to find elements with `<`, index with `loc`, and update -

```
m = df2.concentration.astype(str).str.contains('<')
df2.loc[m, 'concentration'] = \
      pd.to_numeric(df2.loc[m, 'concentration'].str.lstrip('<'), errors='coerce') / 2

df2

  concentration   site
0         12000  site1
1          2000  site2
2            50  site3
3           100  site4
```

Furthermore, `m` records rows under the detection limit.

```
m

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: concentration, dtype: bool
```

Assign it to `df2` -

```
df2['TPH<'] = m
df2

  concentration   site   TPH<
0         12000  site1  False
1          2000  site2  False
2            50  site3   True
3           100  site4   True
```

Keep in mind `concentration` is an object column. I'd recommend a conversion to numeric -

```
df2.concentration = df2.astype(float)
```

Or,

```
df2.concentration = pd.to_numeric(df2.concentration, errors='coerce')
```